# Use iSerialNumber USB device descriptor to uniquely identify GoPro Camera

Tags: linux, usb, udev, gopro, lsusb

The field I'm interested is iSerial from the output of: `lsusb -d <idVendor>:<idProduct> -v`

Example output of a non-unique iSerialNumber:

```
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0402 ALi Corp.
  idProduct          0x9665 Gateway Webcam
  bcdDevice            0.09
  iManufacturer           3 
  iProduct                1 
  iSerial                 0  <-- Three string descriptors exist to provide details of the manufacturer, product and serial number. There is no requirement to have string descriptors. If no string descriptor is present, a index of zero should be used.
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
```

As far as I know the iSerialNumber does not always include a uniquely identifiable string value.
For example the Iphone and Ipad include this information, but some other devices I've tested do not have this value. 
It is not mandatory according to the [USB standard](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#DeviceDescriptors) to have string descriptors.

Can someone who owns a GoPro tell me if it has a string descriptor for the serial number?

I don't have a camera yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine returned **iSerial                 3 123456789ABC**, I tested with Hero3 Black Edition

here is the complete result:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2672:0004  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2672 
  idProduct          0x0004 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 GoPro
  iProduct                2 Storage
  iSerial                 3 123456789ABC
  bNumConfigurations      2
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                4mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     2
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      2
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes, exactly my thought!