# What is USB iSereial param

Tags: linux, uvc, lsusb

I read topic about [iSerial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913121/use-iserialnumber-usb-device-descriptor-to-uniquely-identify-gopro-camera)
I test my devices to get iSerial for my case.
For my JML camera I can get

```
$ lsusb -d 0bda:0567  -v | grep -i serial
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
  iSerial                 2 202001010001
```

For my [ELP-USB4K02AF](https://www.elpcctv.com) camera I can get

```
$ lsusb -d 32e4:0415  -v | grep -i serial
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
  iSerial                 3 01.00.00
```

1. iSerial = [iSerialNumber](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#DeviceDescriptors) ?
2. What is 2 or 3 in iSerial parameter? Index? Why sometimes 2, sometimes 3, sometimes other?
3. Is it typical story: the same cameras from one manufacturer have the same iSerial?

Comment: `iSerial` begins with `i`, meaning it's an **i**ndex into the descriptor's string table.  The specific order of strings in the table will vary from device to device.